# How to edit HTML in Google Drive?

Tags: html, google-drive-api

I have hosted a HTML file created on my PC (along with a stylesheet) on Google Drive using the script described [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/host-website-on-google-drive/28178/).

I have given out the link and it seems to be working fine (no reported issues from those I've sent it to).

I have just discovered a minor omission from the file, I need to add another sentence. This should be ridiculously easy on a PC, I could just open it on notepad!

I can't find a way to edit it on Google Drive, the only connected apps are the viewer and Docs.

The viewer, as the name suggests, will only let me view the HTML, and the docs app won't let me save it back to the original file.

Obviously I could download it then upload again, but from experience it will probably give me a different URL.

Is there any way for me to do this while keeping the link the same, as I have already given the address out?

Comment: In the standard Google Drive web interface, you can right click on a file and select "Manage revisions" and then upload a new version.  When people go to your link they will always see the most recent version (ignoring caching issues..hit refresh a few times).

Answer (score 5):

Currently you can't. You can only preview html files, that is preview the code or preview the rendered content, but you cannot natively edit the code. You have two options:

- use a third party extension, such as [Neutron Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/neutron-drive/lanjfnanlbolmgmnchmhfnicfefjgnff) or [Drive Notepad](https://drivenotepad.appspot.com/).
- install the [Google Drive Desktop App](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive/?hl=en), edit your files locally and save. Changes will be uploaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through file revisions.  Hopefully, Google adds another way, but using the revision feature works for me.  To revise your file, click the check mark in the Google Drive file list, click more, and then click "Manage revisions...".  In the box that pops up, click upload new revision and then you're set.

You may also be able to edit html files stored in google drive through other plugins, but I do not use any at this time to know of them.

Answer (score -1):

Update!

go to drive right click your html file
choose "open with" then "connect more apps"
when app library pop up search for "notepad" then choose "drivenotepad"
after it connect to drive, select it, you will get code editor.

Comment: @Sumurai8 This looks like a valid answer, but the problem is it is very low quality.